# Failed to parse servers response: Expected methodResponse element got br

Tags: xml-rpc

When I try to connect with XmlRpc server on testlink, the error is shown in eclipse console as "The call to the xml-rpc client failed.". The cause of error shown as " org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientException: Failed to parse servers response: Expected methodResponse element got br".

Answer (score 0):

1. Add or change in config.inc.php file

$tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE;

$tlCfg->exec_cfg->enable_test_automation = ENABLED;

2. Add or uncomment in php.ini file

always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

Comment: always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 has to be added at the end of the file or where exactly?